# Parellel tasks in Laravel Scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I basically have a system that's theoretically just a bot, I need to run it on multi-threads (yes I know, it's PHP so not entirely possible) or somewhere along the lines of being able to run an artisan command parallel based on an Eloquent result.

Currently my system looks something like this:

This is my **Kernel.php**

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\RunBuy::class
] 

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('buy:cron')->everyMinute();
}
```

This is my **RunBuy.php**

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle() {
    $this->bot = Bots::where('status', '1')->where('in_use', '0')->first();
    .......
}
```

I basically need the same capability but being able to manage multiple `Bots` depending on how many rows their is? what I'd like to be able to do is something like so:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    foreach(Bots::where('status', '1')->where('in_use', '0')->get() as $bot) {
        $schedule->command('buy:cron '.$bot->id)->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

And then handle it inside the **RunBuy.php** like so:

```
protected $signature = 'buy:cron {bot_id : The Bot ID we must perform actions with}';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle() {
    $bot_id = $this->argument('bot_id');

    $this->bot = Bots::find($bot_id);
    .......
}
```

But something like this wouldn't work since Laravel process each command one after another? I need them all to fire off at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a linux system you can call a command directly with final & to fork the process

```
$schedule->exec('php artisan buy:cron ' . $bot->id . ' > /dev/null &')->everyMinute();
```

On windows you can add a scheduled process to be called to run (a batch which accepts 1 param)
and call it as

```
$schedule->exec('schtasks /run /tn yourtask.bat ' . $bot->id)->everyMinute();
```

yourtask.bat should be a simple php artisan call

```
cd /path/to/project && php artisan buy:cron %1
```

or you can launch each process in background

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    try {
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") {
            pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));
        } else {
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```